# Mongoose Connection issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Not able to connect Mongodb using mongoose getting error

```
/Users/kunal/Documents/Node/Project/taskAccomplisher/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
MongoError: server 127.0.0.1:27017 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"write EPIPE"}
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/kunal/Documents/Node/Project/taskAccomplisher/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:213:40)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/kunal/Documents/Node/Project/taskAccomplisher/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:119:12)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/kunal/Documents/Node/Project/taskAccomplisher/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:151:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:304:10)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:322:5)
    at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:89:5)
    at fireErrorCallbacks (net.js:442:13)
```

> Code used to connect mongodb

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test')
var db  = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
 console.log('Running');
});
```

How can i make mongodb connection with node.js

Comment: Are you definitely sure Mongo is running? What happens when you type `mongo` into a terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongod -repair solved the issue